# I am unable to get my VBA code to save to a created folder

Tags: excel, vba

When using the code below the folder gets created however the sheets that are being exported do not save in the folder, they only save in the path the base file is stored. I have tried everything I can think of or find through searches but they have not corrected the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SplitSheets()       'saves all visible sheets as new xlsx files
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Set wbNew = Application.ThisWorkbook
    sFolderPath = wbNew.Path & "\" & "Import Templates "
    If Dir(sFolderPath) <> "" Then
        'If folder is available
        MsgBox "Folder already exists!", vbInformation, "Import Files"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'If folder is not available
    MkDir sFolderPath
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets                      'for each worksheet
        If ws.Visible Then                                  'if it's visible:
            Debug.Print "Exporting: " & ws.Name
            ws.Copy '(if no params specified, COPY creates + activates a new wb)
            Set wbNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook          'get new wb object
            wbNew.SaveAs sFolderPath & ws.Name & ".csv", 23 'save new wb
            wbNew.Close                                     'close new wb
            Set wbNew = Nothing                             'cleanup
        End If
    Next ws
    Set ws = Nothing                                        'clean up
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot an "\"

Comment: You need to add the trailing `\ ` at the end of  `sFolderPath` - and are you sure you want to have that blank at the end of `"Import Templates "`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite

```
wbNew.SaveAs sFolderPath & ws.Name & ".csv", 23
```

to

```
wbNew.SaveAs sFolderPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv", 23
```

and remove the blank at the end of `sFolderPath = wbNew.Path & "\" & "Import Templates "`.

And instead of exiting the sub insert a proper `else`statement like

```
If Dir(sFolderPath) <> "" Then
    'If folder is available
    MsgBox "Folder already exists!", vbInformation, "Import Files"
Else
    MkDir sFolderPath
   '  ...
   . insert remaining code
End If
```

Comment: This corrected the issue. I found the reason for the continuous 1004 run time error was in fact the space at the end of the "Import Templates". Many thanks!!

Comment: @BillyJenkins remember to mark this answer as correct if it helped with your problem.